# Вывод нечетных чисел через рекурсию Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Это домашка, но никак не могу сделать, буду благодарен хотя-бы совету =) Условие "Дано натуральное число n. Напечатайте все n-значные нечетные натуральные
числа в порядке убывания."

Мой код

```
def rec(n):
    if n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            rec(n-1)

print(rec(30))
```

Comment: rec() ничего не возвращает, поэтому печатать нечего.

Comment: Это у Вас должны распечататься все 30-значные нечетные числа?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Нет, должны распечататься все нечетные цифры, в порядке убывания. От 30 до 0. К примеру 29, 27, 25 и тд.

Comment: "... все n-значные нечетные натуральные числа ..." - это Ваши слова?

Comment: Нет, это слова учителя)

Comment: Вы понимаете, что они значат?

Comment: Вроде как, дано число N к примеру 30. И я так понимаю, что должен распечатать все нечетные числа в порядке убывания.

Comment: N-значное число - это число, состоящее из N цифр. А вовсе даже не число, не превышающее N. А все тридцатизначные числа вывести - это задачка для записного оптимиста...

Comment: мне кажется тут нету стоп-функции, тобеш if n < 0: return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TaEoNVkjT9OKS0EhM00hT8FOwQDEVoCI6xpqgjlgKVUFIyuFgqLMvBKgBi4ukAJjA83//wE)

```
def rec(n):
  if n > 0:
    rec(n-1)
    if n % 2: print(n)

rec(30)
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки переводить строку после двоеточия. Код должен быть единообразным.

Comment: "В порядке убывания". Как этот ответ получил галочку?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну строчки надо местами поменять... А галочку сегодня поставили.

Answer (score 0):

1) Определитесь с задачей - вам нужно N разрядное или N макс число.

2) Если N разрядное, то вы столкнетесь с проблемой рекурсии, нужно будет увеличить ее максимум.

Вот вариант, тут maxNumber - это число которое будет вычисляться. Его можно поставить как максимальное, или вычислить от N разрядов, как возведение 10 в N степень.

```
import sys
n = 4
maxNumber = 10 ** n - 1
sys.setrecursionlimit(maxNumber)
def func(n, i=[]):
    if (n > 0):
        if (n % 2 == 1):
            i.append(n)
        func(n - 2, i)
    return i
result = func(maxNumber)
print(result)
```

Более простой с выводом на экран:

```
import sys
n = 4
maxNumber = 10 ** n - 1
sys.setrecursionlimit(maxNumber)
def func(n):
    if (n > 0):
        if (n % 2 == 1):
            print(n)
        func(n - 2)
func(maxNumber)
```

Без рекурсии:

```
n= 7
maxNumber = 10**n-1
a = [i for i in range(maxNumber) if i%2==1]
print(a)
```

Comment: 1) лучше используйте в языке слова, разделенные `_`, а не верблюжью нотацию (`maxNumber`) 2) скобки в `if` не нужны 3) `def func(n, i=[]):` не используйте изменяемые объекты в аргументах, т.к. значение аргументов сохраняется при объявлении функции и сохраняется при вызовах 4) зачем в первом примере нужен список `i`?

Comment: 4) вызовите повторно `result = func(maxNumber)` и в `result` будет результат предыдущего вызова + нового :) . Лучше явно передавать список в параметры, либо параметр объявить как None, а внутри функции проверить, что если `if i is None: i = []`

Comment: @gil9red в курсе что так будет, но задачи нет вызывать повторно, а так меньше кода) Спасибо за ваш комментарий, возможно, кому-то будет полезен.